# IntegrityError: null value in column "category_id" of relation "message" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I believe this error comes from this line that i might have written incorrectly. Anyone can share why this is written incorrectly in views.py? I understand that I have to specify the this field because it is a foreign key to the model Category:

`message.category_id = self.categories.id`

views.py

```
class AddMessageView(DetailView, FormView):
    model = Room 
    form_class = MessageForm
    template_name = 'add_message.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None): 
        return get_object_or_404(Room, type1__slug=self.kwargs['type1_slug'],slug=self.kwargs['room_slug'])
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        message = form.save(commit=False)
        message.category_id = self.categories.id
        message.name = self.request.user
        message.room = self.get_object()
        message.save()
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

class Room(models.Model):
    categorical = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='categorical', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

class Message(models.Model):
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   room = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name='messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='naming', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assume correctly. `self.categories` Where would this attribute `categories` come from? I assume that the category for a message would be the same as the category for the room, but then why store category for a message? (you can get it from the room anyway i.e. you end up having duplicate data) Anyway if you want the category to be same as the rooms category:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    room = self.get_object()
    message = form.save(commit=False)
    message.category = room.categorical
    message.name = self.request.user
    message.room = room
    message.save()
```

Also why is the related_name for Foreign Key `categorical` the same i.e. `categorical`? Related names are used by the **related** object i.e. category_instance.categorical doesn't make much sense (whereas category_instance.rooms would make much more sense).